# Center tag works fine, but align attribute doesn't! What may be the issue?

Tags: html, css, tags, alignment

I am trying to align a complete page, to the center of a frame, and if I use center tag, it works fine. But, if I use

```
<body align=center>
```

or

```
<body style="align:center">
```

it doesn't align the page, but keep it left-aligned as default. Now, I am a newbie at HTML to be honest, so I don't have much idea, what may be causing this. Also, this happens only in non-IE browsers. IE shows the page center aligned, even without any tags.

Although, it is not of much significance, as I can always use center tag, but its nice to know why align attribute doesn't work. Kindly let me know, if anyone got any idea, as to what is the problem.

Edit:

Turns out, it is because of quirks mode. Thanks David and Town! :D

Comment: There are a couple of answers below that might solve your problem, but if possible please post some HTML to support your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<body align=center>`

Don't use this. The align attribute is deprecated.

> `<body style="align:center">`

CSS is the preferred method but:

- Inline style (the use of the style attribute) should be avoided in favour of real stylesheets.
- There is no `align` property in CSS

Use the `text-align` property if you want to centre the inline content of the element to which you apply it or set the left and right margins to `auto` to centre block elements. For more details, and diagrams, see **[Centring using CSS](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/)**.

> Also, this happens only in non-IE browsers. IE shows the page center aligned, even without any tags.

If you don't have a Doctype that triggers Standards mode, then browsers will emulate bugs in 
earlier browsers (Quirks mode). This is something you should avoid as it makes things much less consistent.

One of these bugs is that Internet Explorer will centre block elements if an ancestor has `text-align: center` set (and won't support auto margins).

Comment: That is the exact issue. IE is using quirks mode, hence the centered version of the body. I do have set doc type to HTML 3.2, as the code is way too big, and with too many shortcuts, it is impossible to convert everything into Strict mode. So, definitely, it is all thanks to quirks mode, that IE is displaying everything centered.

Thanks a lot! Its nice to know stuff, that might save some trouble later. :D

Answer (score 4):

To centre everything within the body, use text-align:

```
style="text-align: center;"
```

To centre an element within its container, give it a width and use margin, like this:

```
style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;"
```

**EDIT:** as other people have suggested, you should use a stylesheet to keep everything tidy.  Put the following in your `<head>` (or reference a separate CSS file).

```
<style type="text/css">
   body { text-align: center; }
</style>
```

Comment: Keeping margin at auto works perfect. Found the same response after searching. Not so sure though, why the align attribute is not working. That's all I am wondering about. 

Anyways thanks for the solution.

Comment: @jitendra garg: If this solution worked for you then click the tick on the left to accept it.  `align` is an HTML attribute and doesn't exist in CSS, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS class. HTML has classes. CSS has class selectors. You don't use either in your examples.

Comment: can accept answers only after 10 minutes, that's why the wait! :D

BTW, I got it working after doing a quick search here. Question was why it was happening. Still upvoted the comment.

Comment: @David Dorward: Sorry, you are indeed correct and my terminology was off. I'd originally used a class selector (`.centered`) in my example, hence the mention of classes.  If you want to add that comment on every mention of 'CSS class' on SO then I don't envy the task ahead of you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the CSS tag you want is "text-align" not "align".  Also, you should try and avoid inline styling, whenever possible use a stylesheet; it helps to keep all of your styling together in one place, and lets the browser cache the styling.

Comment: text-align attribute is already set to center, but still getting everything left aligned in firefox. Margin solution works fine for all browsers, as I have tested it just now.